# Estimate room energy loss from temperature plots

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, heat-conduction

What is the method for determining the heat/energy loss from a room, given a temperature plot/delta and a measure of the energy input over time ?

I'm building an extension to our house, and have really doubled down on the insulation. Currently one room is finished and fully insulated. As it's cold outside (-1C) I thought it a good time to measure how effective the insulation it. There is no heat source active in the room, and the room was stable at about 4C.

With some calculations of the insulation thickness and conductivity, I estimate the U-value of the walls to be 0.15 W/m2/K. The wall area is 100m2, Volume ~200m3. The windows have a U value of about 1.0, and are 2m2.

So putting this together, I estimate that for every degree of difference between inside and outside temperature, I'd need 0.15 * 100 + 1 * 2 = 15+2 = 17W of power to maintain this temperature, e.g. with -1C outside and 4C inside, 17 * 5 = 85W.

I turned on a 1KW heater for 2.5 hours and looked at the temperature rise. The results were not what I expected - the room rose by about ~2 degrees over that time. A plot of the temperature started to show the temp rise levelling off at the end of the 2.5 hours, which was surprising.

So the question is - from this information of the heat-source and temperature rise, can the true U value of this room be determined?

A plot of the temperature change is shown here:
The x-axis shows temperature samples every 30 seconds. The series are 3 different temp sensors - there is some sensor to sensor offset, but all are showing the same trend. Between samples ~230 and ~550 this represents 2.5 hours and shows a rise from 6C to 8C, which is when the room had the 1KW heater active. Over the next 9 hours the room cools to 4.7C from 8C.
Outside temperature was constant at -1C, and there outside conditions were calm (no wind chill).
[image: heat loss graph]

Comment: Are you taking into account heat loss by convection (e.g., loss on a windy day)?

Comment: No, purely conductive loss due to insulation. How much difference can convection make to the exterior of a building?

Comment: How much difference? Did you ever hear of the wind chill factor?

Comment: Yes, but usually that is expressed as a few degrees c below ambient. In this case we can assume this is 0 as when measured outside conditions were calm

Comment: Well then, you now have told us that you did your experiment on a day when outside conditions were "calm", we now know that you did consider convective heat loss. If you said that in your post, I wouldn't  have made my comment.

Comment: Makes sense, the question is edited to state this. I also added the temperature plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an approximation you can use [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law):

$$-mc_p\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=UA[T(t)-T_e]\tag{1}$$

As your room is made of walls and windows, you'd have to work it as:

$$UA\approx U_{walls}A_{walls}+U_{windows}A_{windows}$$

$m$ is the mass of the content of the room: assuming it's empty that's air.

$(1)$ is a simple ordinary differential equation, at least provided $T_e=\text{constant}$. Firstly we define the so-called *characteristic time* $\tau$:

$$\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{UA}{mc_p}$$

So that:

$$-\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=\frac{1}{\tau}[T(t)-T_e]\tag{2}$$

$(2)$ solves to:

$$\ln\frac{T(t)-T_e}{T_0-T_e}=-\frac{t}{\tau}$$

which gives you the *theoretical* evolution of $T(t)$ in time $t$. $T_0$ is the initial ($t=0$) room temperature.

By plotting the $\text{LHS}$ vs. the $t$ in (e.g.) Excel you should obtain a straight line with slope $\frac{1}{\tau}$.

From that value, $U$ can then be calculated.

[image: Correlation]

where:

$$\Theta=\ln\frac{T(t)-T_e}{T_0-T_e}$$

$\Theta$ is sometimes called the *reduced temperature*.

Comment: Thanks. I added a plot of the temperature, and it does show the exponential decay response, but do not know how to relate this to the equation you show here. Could you help take it to the next step?

Comment: The second part (from $t>600$) shows the behaviour described by NLoC. But you need to plot $\ln\frac{T(t)-T_e}{T_0-T_e}$ vs time, to get the slope of the graph.

Comment: Just to confirm, is Te the end temp and T0 the start temp?

Comment: $T_e$ is the outside temperature, assumed to be constant. $T_0$ is the initial room temperature.

Comment: If you like my answer, please upvote it or accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I just up voted it, seems as I'm new to physics. Stack Exchange it does not show up. I'll give what you suggest a try and if it works will accept the answer. The post itself also has no votes, maybe if som folks vote for it I can have sufficient reputation to vote for answers.

Comment: Hmmm... very strange...

Comment: Thanks for the 'accept' upvote.